# Set id inside filter on serializer automatically

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to get the total count from specific Model inside a Serialization.

```
"results": [
    {
       "event_id": 24,
       "unique_visitors": 1,
       "returned_visitors": 2
    },
]
```

The two value that i retrive in `unique_visitors` and `returned_visitors` come from one other module.
What i did in `serializer.py`:

```
unique_visitors = EventCounter.objects.filter(is_unique=True).filter(event_id=24).count()
returned_visitors = EventCounter.objects.filter(is_unique=False).filter(event_id=24).count()

def get_unique_visitors(self, obj):
    return self.unique_visitors

def get_returned_visitors(self, obj):
    return self.returned_visitors
```

What i try to do is to have inside the `filter(event_id=24)` the id of current object automatically.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Are you using the serializer for EventCounter model?

Answer (score 0):

So to achieve the desired result, you have to use `SerializerMethodField()`.

This is a read-only field. It gets its value by calling a method on the serializer class it is attached to.

For example

```
from rest_framework import serializers

...
unique_visitors = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
returned_visitors = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
...

def get_unique_visitors(self, obj):
    unique_visitors = EventCounter.objects.filter(is_unique=True)\
                                      .filter(event_id=24).count()
    return unique_visitors

def get_returned_visitors(self, obj):
    returned_visitors = EventCounter.objects.filter(is_unique=False)\
                                      .filter(event_id=24).count()
    return returned_visitors
```

`SerializerMethodField` also accepts one optional param called `method_name` you can add it to change the name of the method that the field is attached to.
If not included this defaults to `get_<field_name>`.

Check the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for more info.